# How to fix "Canonical released microcode updates for both Intel and AMD"?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

For Ubuntu Desktop `22.04` after to execute the `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` commands, for the latter appears:

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  imagemagick libopenexr25 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-6
  imagemagick-6.q16 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 imagemagick-6-common
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
#
# Canonical released microcode updates for both Intel (CVE-2022-40982) and AMD
# (CVE-2023-20593). ‘Unattended upgrades’ provide security updates by default.
# Ensure it remains enabled to always get all updates as they become available.
#
The following packages have been kept back:
  gjs libgjs0g
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

How to fix that?